# spring-boot actuator response code changed from 200 OK to 200 causing alarm in icinga

Tags: spring-boot, monitoring, spring-boot-actuator, http-response-codes, icinga2

boot technology. In production environment We are having kubernetes cluster. we are monitoring all the services using `actuator/info` endpoint. Somehow after last deployment `actuator/info` endpoints response code which was set to `200 OK` in expected field is now changed to `200` which is causing alarm in icinga dashboard. Is there any mechanism to change it back to `200 OK` I've asked dev team about this change but they've no idea about this code change. I am wondering about which piece would make this kind of change in application response code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you’re using Tomcat. It stopped sending the reason phrase in an update in mid-2016. The reason phrase is optional and the relevant RFC recommends that clients ignore it. Perhaps your monitoring tool can be configured to follow that recommendation? There’s some more background in [this Spring Boot issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6548).